# How to call method of a class with wildcard in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I can't call method `serve()` below.

```
public class GenericService {

   public static class Service<T> {

      public void serve(T t) {
         System.out.println(t.toString());
      }

   }

   public static Service<?> service = new Service<String>();

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      service.serve("Hello World!"); // 'serve(capture<?>)' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

   }
}
```

How to call this method by force?

Why does Java dislike such calls?

**UPDATE**

The problem is not `ClassCastException` as was proposed, because in that case I would be able to write

```
      try {
         service.serve("Hello World!"); // 'serve(capture<?>)' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'
      }
      catch (ClassCastException e) {
         System.err.println("You see!? This is why I was disliking your code!");
      }
```

but I can't.

Why?

**UPDATE 2**

Now, when everybody said out, a new version:

```
   public static Service<? extends String> service = new Service<String>();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      service.serve("Hello World!"); // 'serve(capture<?>)' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

      ((Service<String>)service).serve("Hello World!");  // Unchecked cast: 'GenericService.Service<capture<? extends String>>' to 'GenericService.Service<String>'
   }
```

what problem is here (don't regard that `String` is `final`)?

Comment: You cannot, that's the point. What if it were a `Service<Foo>`? You have said wanted a `Service` of type "I don't care", which means that it could be anything. The fact that you assigned `Service<String>` is neither here nor there...

Comment: Why? `service` variable references an object, which CAN process `String`. Why can't I TELL it to do this?

Comment: What's the definition of the service class?  It looks like serve takes a `capture`, not a string.

Comment: Why not make `service` a reference type `Service<String>`?

Comment: @puhlen defenitions are all there; an example is self containing

Comment: @Zircon why should I? By what reason?

Comment: Maybe the example is over-simplifying your scenario, but if you know `service` poiints to a `Service<String>`, there's no reason to make the reference type anything different.

Comment: @Zircon I am asking from service usage side, not from service providing

Comment: Lets approach this a different way; why do you thing that you should be able to call `serve` with a `String` on a `Service<?>`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider this is my question: what if there were `Service<Foo>`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider because of the first law of robotics: machine must obey direct orders of a human

Comment: @Dims [2nd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics). Come on! And in this case, the 1st law applies - doing what you ask would mean that you come to harm; via a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider no, this is NOT the case; otherwise hint me how to cause `ClassCastException` here.

Comment: Because you could have declared it as a `Service<Foo>`, then `service.serve("Hello World!")` would cause a `ClassCastException`; agreed? So what makes your assignment of `Service<String>` any different? The compile time type of your `Service` is still the same.

Comment: @BoristheSpider no, I disagree. If I pass string to `Service<Foo>` it will also print some result, because all classes have `toString()` method. So, no any place to raise `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Incidentally, with your laws you have created a [robot hellscape](https://xkcd.com/1613/). Maybe don't program robots; please.

Comment: But you have said that your `Service` method takes some type `T`, which is a generic type. You have then said that the `T` is a `Foo`. Then you pass in a `String`. Bang.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I will, don't even ask :D

Comment: Your next problem is [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). Again, the wildcard does not mean "any" type it means "some, unknown" type - it could be a `Service<Bar>` where `Bar extends String`. The fact that `String` is `final` is not taken into account.

Comment: @BoristheSpider absolutely

Answer (score 8):

You misunderstand what the wildcard means (this is actually a common misunderstanding about generics wildcards in Java).

`Service<?>` does **not** mean: a `Service` that can accept any type.

It **does** mean: a `Service` of a specific, but unknown type.

You cannot call `serve`, passing it a `String`, because the type that the `?` stands for is unknown - the compiler cannot check, just by looking at the type of the variable `service`, if the actual service that it refers to is a `Service<String>`, a `Service<Integer>` or a `Service<Whatever>`, so it can't know if it should be allowed to pass a `String` to the `serve` method.

To keep it type-safe, the compiler has no other option than to not allow you to call the method.

> How to call this method by force?

You can force it by casting:

```
((Service<String>) service).serve("Hello World!");
```

(But keep in mind that casting means you are giving up on type-safety, in general you should avoid casting as much as possible).

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards in generics has not for aim to allow the usage of any type. It is a way to identify an unknown and invariable type.

In your code, `?` is of type `String` but the compiler can't guess it. You could change it later with a `Service<Integer>` and have `ClassCastException` at runtime by forcing `String` objects in it.

There is no way to cast an object to a captured type (= wildcard).

If you want to accept every object that declare the `toString()` method then you should use `Service<Object>` instead of `Service<?>`:

```
public static Service<Object> service = new Service<Object>();
```

Comment: You cannot assign a `Service<String>` to a `Service<Object>`. Apart from that, this answer is good.

Comment: The question is not about I can't, the question is about how to overcome this limitation and why it is exist

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks

Comment: @Dims it's not a limitation, it's an important feature. This question explains exactly why this is the case.

Comment: @BoristheSpider no, the answer just states that I cannot do various things. I don't see any reason for this. If compiler can't guess something -- I can hint him